# Style reference works on UWP but not on Android or Wasm

Tags: xaml, uno-platform

I have defined a Style as a `UserControl`'s resource.

```xml
...
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="BottomBarButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Target="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
      <Setter Target="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
      <Setter Target="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      <Setter Target="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
```

and it's used

```xml
...
<Button Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource BottomBarButton}">
  ...
</Button>
<Button Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource BottomBarButton}">
  ...
</Button>
...
```

This work on UWP, but the style does not apply on Android or Wasm. These are the only tested platforms

Comment: Could you indicate which version of the Uno.UI package you are using ?

Comment: @JérômeLaban Uno 2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must use `Property` instead of `Target`.

```
<Style x:Key="BottomBarButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the style named "ButtonStyle" but are referencing a style named "BottomBarButton" (which I'm guessing is defined elsewhere).

Tried this?

```xml
<Button Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
  ...
</Button>
<Button Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
  ...
</Button>
```

Comment: That's a good catch on my quickly thrown together sample, however unfortunately that's a mistake in my question and not the actual code I wrote.